# Alternatives to Hue to access Apache Hive

Tags: toad, hue, bigdata

We are using Hue, and also Toad for users to access Hive on our Big Data environment.

- We have found Hue to work fine if you would like to quickly browse a small set of data, and view schemas.
- We have found Toad better when it comes to execute more resourceful queries that take longer since it's an application and avoiding HTTP timeouts or browsers hanging/crashing... Intellisense also helps a lot. However Toad sometimes doesn't display results, and seems to be buggy - connections are sometimes not saved, intellisense stops working sometimes and jobs are not submitted.

Has anyone any good recommendations for open source tools, or commercial ones that are alternatives to the mentioned tools, and possible better when it comes to browse schemas/execute hive queries?

Comment: The audience are not advanced users and would need a UI similar to SSMS.

Comment: That is good feedback, thanks! Which Hue version? Note that 3.10 comes with a revamped SQL editor that manages its states correctly and 3.11 will bring a solid Intellisense. Hue does not do any real processing as it submits the query to HiveServer2, but performances are being worked on when thousand of columns are returned as it can indeed freeze the browser as of today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two tools proved more stable and reliable

- Apache Toad
- DBeaver